How do I print specific variables in a separate terminal? (like seeing specific information in real time)
I'm using VSCode to execute a python script, inside I'm doing a large amount of iterations to check if something pass or fails, the thing is that there is a lot of information (logging) in terminal, what I need is to print specific information in other terminal to see the current status if something fails in X iteration while the script is running.
Let say:
import logging

for i in range(1000)
   # do stuff
    if something == my_variable:
        logging.info('pass')
    else:
        logging.error('fail')
        print(f'Error in {my_variable} in cycle {i}') #This is what i need in terminal 2

So basically is to have two vscode windows opened or split where the second terminal show only the print in code example

What about writing the logging messages to a file and track the file content with tail  in the second terminal?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

All the logging is being recorded in a file txt, let me check what "tail" means in python

tail isn't python, it's a Unix command you type in a shell window.

tail -f filename will continuously print the file contents as new lines are added to it.

I'm sorry, i'm using windows OS

You can create a logger and send logs to multiple different handlers. You can set the level of the logger and then set the stream/s to different debug levels.
In the code below I log to streamhandler(terminal):  info(), warning(), error() and critical()
Filehandler will log only error() and critical()
In nix systems you can watch your terminal code and then in another terminal you can tail -f log.txt to watch the output of higher errors.
import logging

# set up Logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add Handlers
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
fh = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", "w")
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.addHandler(fh)

for i in range(1000):
   # do stuff
    if i % 2 == 0:
        logger.info('pass')
    else:
        logger.error('fail')
        logger.error(f'Error in  in cycle {i}') #This is what i need in terminal 2

Because you have windows i would stream the 2nd handler in a different colour:
fh = logging.StreamHandler()
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
fh.formatter = logging.Formatter("\x1b[31;1m %(message)s \x1b[0m")

colour

Each of your terminal windows (or tabs) has a virtual terminal allocated, which you can find out with the command tty. Now say that the terminal you want your variable to be logged is /dev/ttys0001. In this case, write in your Python program your logging information to the file /dev/ttys0001.
